# SSIS ODBC Source update causing cast errors

Tags: sql-server, ssis, kingswaysoft

I am running into an issue where every time I add a new column to my ODBC Source component I get the following error when I run it:

> Invalid character value for cast specification

The only resolution I have is to remove the component and make it again with the new column. When I run it after this it works completely fine.

This is a pain having to do this every time, is there a way I can fix this? I have tried rebuilding my project and even deleting my bin/obj folders and rebuilding and nothing else works.

My SSIS package is pretty simple in that I select columns and am mapping them to a Kingswaysoft Salesforce component.

Comment: Need more information about the situation to better assist you. Is this happening to a Salesforce destination component with Bulk API enabled? If so, can you try to disconnect the destination component from upstream component and then reconnect to see if it helps? If that does not help, please reach out to us through our official support channel, we might be able to assist you from there.

Comment: @DanielCai this isn't a solution to the problem but I moved away from using the ODBC component and switched to the OLE DB component and it worked perfectly.